# Which shloka describes human qualities?

Tags: shloka, reference-request

Where can I find the collection of shlokas on the great human qualities?

Qualities like perseverance, hardworking, visionary, Kind, Passionate Honesty and Integrity etc?

Comment: Welcome to the site!! Are you asking collection of slokas?

Comment: Thanks @AkshayS!. Do u know any reference about this?